# How can I write regex for the following statements?

Tags: regex, pcre

I have some strings, and I would like to use regex to extract any html tags, and also the text from a set of curly braces.

For example, I can have the following 2 strings:

```
Is this a { <strong>  Versioned placeholder </strong> } file?
Is this a  <strong> { Versioned placeholder } </strong> file?
```

And so far, I have the following regex:

```
(?:\{)(?<PlaceholderValue>\s*[\w\s]*\s*)(?:\})
```

What I would like is for the text within the curly braces (i.e. "*Versioned placeholder*") to be placed in the *PlaceholderValue* group, and all other html tags WITHIN the curly braces to also be captured. How can I do this?

Note, the html tags within the curly braces are optional, and will not always be present. I am not interested if the html tags are outside the curly braces.

Comment: What is the regex flavor? PCRE? See [`(?:{|(?!^)\G)\s*\K(<[^>]+>|[^<>}]+\b)` demo](https://regex101.com/r/vZ6wK1/1).

Comment: Yes, PCRE. Your solution works correctly, but I would still like the value "Versioned placeholder" to be held in the variable _PlaceholderValue_

Comment: Isn't that cosmetic requirement? Just add this group around the second branch, see https://regex101.com/r/vZ6wK1/2, or even [`(?:{|(?!^)\G)\s*\K(?:(?<tag><[^>]+>)|(?<PlaceholderValue>[^<>}]+)\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/vZ6wK1/3).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew perfect, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:{|(?!^)\G)\s*\K(?:(?<tag><[^>]+>)|(?<PlaceholderValue>[^<}]*[^<}\s]))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vZ6wK1/4)

The pattern matches:

- `(?:{|(?!^)\G)` - a `{` or the end of the previous successful match
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces (to trim from the left)
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `(?:(?<tag><[^>]+>)|(?<PlaceholderValue>[^<}]*[^<}\s]))` - A group of 2 alternatives:

  - `(?<tag><[^>]+>)` - Group "tag" matching a `<`, 1+ chars other than `<` and `>`, and a `>`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<PlaceholderValue>[^<}]*[^<}\s])` - Group "PlaceholderValue" capturing 0+ chars other than `<` and `}` as many as possible, and then an obligatory character that is not a whitespace, `<` and `}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\{ )(.*?)(?= \})
```

This should work depending on what regex you're using

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in javascript:

```js
var string1 = 'Is this a { <strong>  Versioned placeholder </strong> } file?';
var string2 = 'Is this a  <strong> { Versioned placeholder } </strong> file?';

var reg = /<(strong)>[\{\}\w\s]+<\/\1>/;

alert(string1.match(reg)[0].replace(/<strong>|<\/strong>|{|}/g, ''));
alert(string2.match(reg)[0].replace(/<strong>|<\/strong>|{|}/g, ''));
```